# Custom Class Cannot Inflate Properly in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview, android-custom-view

In the past I used LinearLayout programmaticaly when I used SurfaceView.  I thought that I'd challenge myself by writing my own stopwatch using SurfaceView  and XML layout.  I've studied the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915124/android-adding-custom-surfaceview-to-xml-defined-surfaceview-not-working?rq=1).   My XML is

```
    <com.spazzkeys.tutorial.ClockView
        android:id="@+id/clockView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

My   constructor is:

```
public ClockView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    secHandPaint = new Paint(Color.BLACK);
```

And my inflater look like this:

```
    myClock = (ClockView)findViewById(R.id.clockView1);
```

Everything that I've learned indicates that this should work but it doesn't.

I guess I don't understand how inflating a view, through (XML) resources, transfers the context.  Second, how does clockView know what the bounds are so it knows how big to be?

Any thoughts would be appreciated (before I go back coding my layout).

Thanks.

Chris

Comment: Can you please show full java code.

Comment: `Everything that I've learned indicates that this should work but it doesn't` "it doesn't work" is a useless statement.  What exactly happens?

Answer (score 0):

This is example, I am showing. Did you inflate like this ?

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);
EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);
```

Comment: What I had was:
// SurfaceView myClock;
 ClockView myClock;
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.clock_view_with_custom_view);
  myClock = (ClockView)findViewById(R.id.clockView1);
//  myClock =(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.clockView1);

Comment: I also tried:
  LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
  theView = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.clock_view_with_custom_view, null);
  myClock = (ClockView)theView.findViewById(R.id.clockView1);
  setContentView(R.layout.clock_view_with_custom_view);

Comment: I get an Error inflating Class Exception. It doesn't like my        <com.spazzkeys.tutorial.ClockView XML statement.  What am I missing?

Comment: Add this property to your only XML node: xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"